# In Java how should I compare an object to a const value?

Tags: java, null, compare, equality

I've created my own `MyDate` class. It basically wraps a `Long` value with some pretty `toString()` functions. I've implemented `equals()` and `compareTo()`. my program reads some data and instantiates object of classes that hold this `MyDate` class. Problem is that sometimes that data is bad so I created a `public static final long NODATE = Long.MIN_VALUE;` so that I could initiate a new instance that is empty (replace the null in the containing class so to avoid NullPointerExceptions). I've also implemented a constructor with no arguments that inits the `Long` value to `NODATE`.

My Problem:
I want to check if a `MyDate` is valued as `NODATE`. I can't compare to `NODATE` since it's `Long` and not `MyDate`. One way to do this is:

`if someObject.myDate.equals(new MyDate())`.

But it seems like a waste to create an object just to make the comparison? Another way is to implement `MyDate.amINoDate()` method.

Is there another way? I was thinking of creating an static instance of `MyDate` that is inited to NODATE and to compare to it. But how can I compare my non static objects to this static object?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyDate {
  public static final MyDate NODATE = new MyDate(Long.MIN_VALUE);
  // ...
}

// ...
if (someDate.equals(MyDate.NODATE)) // ...
```

Thanks maskacovnik.

Comment: Great. Exactly what I was looking for. Accpeted and plused.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add a method to `MyDate` like:

```
public boolean isNodate() {
    return internalLongDate == Long.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: this is amINODATE() method I was reffering to. +1 for the better name.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to MyDate:

```
if (someDate.isNoDate()) {
    ...
}
```

Also: personally I would avoid the Long.MIN_VALUE and use null.